# Error in mongodb logs Failed to gather storage statistics for slow operation- lock acquire timeout

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb for my application where the document are being updated every 30 minutes, the logs are showing the following message consistently

```
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-02-25T05:31:18.018+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20525,   "ctx":"conn2660",
"msg":"Failed to gather storage statistics for slow operation",
"attr":{"opId":421679,"error":"lock acquire timeout"}}
```

I am observing a slow time in the MongoDB operations when this error message occurs, I already have added the indexes and they are performing well so I am not sure what is causing issue and how to fix this.

```
Mongodb version 4.4.18
```

Please help.